# systemd -- su: Permission denied, in /etc/init.d scripts

Tags: rhel, systemd, su, sysvinit

We are migrating from RHEL6 to RHEL8
and I would like to retain the old `/etc/init.d` scripts,
since we have a ton of applications that would otherwise
need be rewritten and tested.

For many init-scripts, the backwards compatibility work OK.

But for other scripts that switch from root to application-specific users,
where we do:

```
  su - username -c "application-start-script"
```

they fail during reboot-startup with

```
  su: Pemission denied.
```

Still, **starting them manually** with `systemctl` **works**.
It's only during reboot-startup we get this failure.

I have verified (with `whoami`) that the script
runs as **root** in both cases.

So, my question:

**How/why can `su` fail when running as root during systemd startup?**

Comment: Any selinux AVCs in the audit log during boot?

Comment: thanks for the hint, jsb. Im not very familiar with seLinux, but when I disabled it the error disappeared. Strangely, when I enabled it again and rebooted, the error did not come back. So at the moment it seems to work. Confusing...

Answer (score 8):

Wanted to chime in on this, even though it's already marked as resolved, because some people don't have the option to disable SELinux.

In the `init.d` directory, use `ls -Z` to see the SELinux contexts of all the files. Your script likely has the wrong context compared to the other startup scripts, so you want to change it to match. Easiest is run

```
sudo chcon --reference=nameofascriptthatworks yourscriptname
```

and verify the context was set properly with another `ls -Z`.

Comment: SOLR 9.2.1 has an installation script that places a script into folder /etc/init.d. On Rocky Linux 8.8, the service would not start until I used this answer to specify the following: sudo chcon -v system_u:object_r:bin_t:s0 solr

Comment: @Doraemon Thank you so much your answer! It was a lifesaver for me.

Answer (score 1):

I'm seeing the same problem here with getting a script to start Oracle not working.  If you look in /var/messages, you'll see an selinux error saying it's not permitted.  I'm working on CentOS, and I changed the selinux config from enforcing to permissive.  After that it worked fine.  For me, it's just a development VM, so the security wasn't an issue.  The messages file also had a way to exempt just a single init.d service, that might be worth a try too.

cat /etc/selinux/config

```
# This file controls the state of SELinux on the system on boot.

# SELINUX can take one of these three values:
#       enforcing - SELinux security policy is enforced.
#       permissive - SELinux prints warnings instead of enforcing.
#       disabled - No SELinux policy is loaded.
SELINUX=permissive
```